# Get response from rabbitmq for the published message. Golang

Tags: go, rabbitmq, rpc, amqp

I have implemented worker that consumes messages, do some type of job with them and publish result on the queue.

I have api, which will receive http request, publish message to the worker and wait for the worker to send response.

I have two queues, one is worker and the other one is gateway.

Api will -> Publish events on the worker queue. Consume events from the gateway queue (wait for response)
Worker will -> Consume events from the worker queue. Publish events on the gateway queue.

Worker works great, and i have never had problems with it. So i will focus on the api, because there is where the error is.

Problem:

Every time when my api publish message. It will first generate some uuid which we will remember in our map so when we consume response. We can match it for which request that response is.

When we consume message, first time everything works great, we can match response with the request. But second time, we can't find that response in our map. Even though i have added it.

Here are some code examples.

Storage, interface that will work with map

```
package main

import "fmt"

type ChannelStorage interface {

    Add(uid string, message chan ResponseMessage)
    Delete(uid string)
    Get(uid string) chan ResponseMessage
}

func NewChannelStorage() ChannelStorage {
    return ChannelMapStorage{
        channelMap: make(map[string]chan ResponseMessage),
    }
}

type ChannelMapStorage struct {
    channelMap map[string]chan ResponseMessage
}

func (storage ChannelMapStorage) Add(uid string, message chan ResponseMessage) {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Adding Message: %s ", uid))
    storage.channelMap[uid] = message
}

func (storage ChannelMapStorage) Delete(uid string) {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Deleting Message: %s ", uid))
    delete(storage.channelMap, uid)
}

func (storage ChannelMapStorage) Get(uid string) chan ResponseMessage {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Getting Message: %s ", uid))
    return storage.channelMap[uid]
}
```

This is my publisher that will send events to the worker queue.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

var channel *amqp.Channel

func init()  {

    // Connect to the rabbit.
    conn, err := amqp.Dial(rabbitConfig.uri)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // create channel
    channel, err = conn.Channel()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func publish(queueName string , data []byte, id string) error {

    // publish message
    return channel.Publish(
        "",            // exchange
        queueName, // routing key
        false,         // mandatory
        false,         // immediate
        amqp.Publishing{
            CorrelationId: id,
            ContentType: "text/plain",
            Body:        data,
        },
    )

}
```

Here is sender, this is part of the code, where all the action happens.
It's job is to connect to the rabbitmq, consume events. Match events with the request and notify that we got response.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func init()  {

    conn, err := amqp.Dial(rabbitConfig.uri)

    failOnError(err, "Publisher failed to connect to the rabbitmq")

    // Create channel
    channel, err := conn.Channel()

    failOnError(err, "Publisher failed to create channel")

    // Create queue
    queue, err := channel.QueueDeclare(
        RECIEVE_QUEUE_NAME, // channelname
        true,      // durable
        false,     // delete when unused
        false,     // exclusive
        false,     // no-wait
        nil,       // arguments
    )

    failOnError(err, "Failed to create queue for consumer")

    // channel
    messages, err := channel.Consume(
        queue.Name, // queue
        "",         // consumer
        true,      // auto-ack
        false,      // exclusive
        false,      // no-local
        false,      // no-wait
        nil,        // args
    )

    failOnError(err, "Failed on consuming event")

    go func() {
        for message:= range messages {
            go handleMessage(message)
        }
    }()
}

func sendMessage(name string, id string ,requestType string) ([]byte, int, error) {

    // Create new task message
    message := TaskMessage{
        Uid: uid(),
        ReplyTo: RECIEVE_QUEUE_NAME,
        Type: requestType,
        Name: name,
        Id: id,
    }

    data ,err := json.Marshal(message)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Cant unmarshall message %s", err.Error()))
        return nil, 0, err
    }

    err = publish(SEND_QUEUE_NAME, data, message.Uid)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Cant publish message %s", err.Error()))
        return nil, 0, err
    }

    // whenever we send message, we need to add it to the waiting response channel
    rchannel := make(chan ResponseMessage)
    channelStorage.Add(message.Uid, rchannel)

    // Wait for the response
    select {

    case response := <- rchannel:

        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Sending response: %s ", message.Uid))

        data := response.Response
        code := response.StatusCode

        channelStorage.Delete(message.Uid)

        return data, code, nil

    case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):

        // remove channel from rchans
        channelStorage.Delete(message.Uid)

        // Return timeout error.
        return nil, 0, errors.New("Response timed out on rabbit.")
    }
}

func handleMessage(msg amqp.Delivery)  {

    // Parse message.
    response := &ResponseMessage{}

    // Parse response.
    err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Body, response)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("ERROR: fail unmarshl: %s", msg.Body)
        return
    }

    // find waiting channel(with uid) and forward the reply to it
    if channel := channelStorage.Get(response.Uid); channel != nil {
        channel <- *response
    }
}
```

Method sendMessage() will publish event, wait for the consume response. Map it with our request and return result.

Here i will create new Task

```
// Create new task message
    message := TaskMessage{
        Uid: uid(),
        ReplyTo: RECIEVE_QUEUE_NAME,
        Type: requestType,
        Name: name,
        Id: id,
    }

    data ,err := json.Marshal(message)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Cant unmarshall message %s", err.Error()))
        return nil, 0, err
    }
```

Publish task with method from publisher.go

```
err = publish(SEND_QUEUE_NAME, data, message.Uid)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Cant publish message %s", err.Error()))
        return nil, 0, err
    }
```

Use our storage interface to map response with unique id which we generated.

```
rchannel := make(chan ResponseMessage)
channelStorage.Add(message.Uid, rchannel)
```

Wait for the channel that will notify is when we get response for our published event. Our timeout if we do not get response in 3 seconds.

```
case response := <- rchannel:

        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Sending response: %s ", message.Uid))

        data := response.Response
        code := response.StatusCode

        channelStorage.Delete(message.Uid)

        return data, code, nil

    case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):

        // remove channel from rchans
        channelStorage.Delete(message.Uid)

        // Return timeout error.
        return nil, 0, errors.New("Response timed out on rabbit.")
    }
```

Problem happens, when we consume message, but try to map id with the response. It says that it returns nil for the id from our map.

```
func handleMessage(msg amqp.Delivery)  {

    // Parse message.
    response := &ResponseMessage{}

    // Parse response.
    err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Body, response)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("ERROR: fail unmarshl: %s", msg.Body)
        return
    }

    // find waiting channel(with uid) and forward the reply to it
    if channel := channelStorage.Get(response.Uid); channel != nil {
        channel <- *response
    }
}
```

My main.go looks like this, it will create global storage and run http server:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var channelStorage ChannelStorage

func main()  {

    channelStorage = NewChannelStorage()

    err := SetupRouter(NewApi()).Run(":8080")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

As i am not so much experienced with golang. The problem might happen because i create global storage or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

First: your storage are not thread safe now and you should use sync.Mutex for example.

```
type ChannelMapStorage struct {
    m sync.Nutex
    channelMap map[string]chan ResponseMessage
}

func (storage *ChannelMapStorage) Add(uid string, message chan ResponseMessage) {
    storage.m.Lock()
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Adding Message: %s ", uid))
    storage.channelMap[uid] = message
    storage.m.Unlock()
}
```

Same thing for all other methods.

Second: You should add message to storage before publish and remove it if publish was failed.

```
data ,err := json.Marshal(message)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Cant unmarshall message %s", err.Error()))
    return nil, 0, err
}

rchannel := make(chan ResponseMessage)
channelStorage.Add(message.Uid, rchannel)

err = publish(SEND_QUEUE_NAME, data, message.Uid)
if err != nil {
    channelStorage.Del(message.Uid)
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Cant publish message %s", err.Error()))
    return nil, 0, err
}
```